# Separate pages vs updating components on the same page

Tags: reactjs, components

So I am just wondering if there are any common practices or basic guidelines as to when you should create separate pages vs just updating the components on the current page when using React? I tried to look online and could not find anything.

Comment: take a look at this [react file structure](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html)

Comment: One main reason would be to bookmark a page or share its link, also be able to let users to directly go in a specific location. Another, maybe even more important, is  separation of concerns

Answer (score 1):

There are some scenarios in which you need your data or some state persisted, just some update in the UI, like Atlassian Login page.
When you  write your email, it changes the route and changes some css (changes password field display from `none` to `block`).

Or in Jira next gen, there are tasks, if you click on one of the tasks in a scrum board, the page component is the same, but it brings up a modal component showing up the details of that task.

Why different routes? cause you can share the link and whenever someone navigates to that route, it brings up the page with the same UI that you saw when you copied the link.

Otherwise it's a cleaner approach to handle navigation using separate pages. So it's totally up to you and the kind of UI/UX design.